# Find an equation of the tangent line.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I am not sure how I would continue this problem from where I am at, this is the original equation.$$y=9(\cosh x-\sinh x)^2  \quad (0,9)$$ This is what I have so far. $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=18(\cosh x-\sinh x)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$$ Not sure how I would continue this problem, plugging in $0$ gives me an imaginary number.

Comment: $(\cosh)'=\sinh$ and $\cosh=(\sinh)'$.

Comment: Ok thank you i will try that. Man wow I just noticed that those derivatives are for the inverses.

Comment: That would make it harder to get the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the facts that $\frac d {dx} \cosh x = \sinh x$ and $\frac d {dx} \sinh x = \cosh x$.

But why do even that, unless you want to practise your use of hyperbolic functions?

From the definitions of $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x$ it can be shown that:

$$\cosh x - \sinh x \equiv \frac {e^x+e^{-x}}2-\frac {e^x-e^{-x}}2=e^{-x}$$

Then $\left(\cosh x - \sinh x\right)^2 \equiv =\left(e^{-x}\right)^2=e^{-2x}$ and it all becomes a bit simple!